# Enry point not found while call C++ dll from C# application

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have simple C++ dll function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int tst1(int a);

int  tst1(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

I have C# application that calls it:

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll")] 
public static extern int tst1(int i);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(  tst1(1) ); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Got `EntryPointNotFoundException` error:

[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: it's hard to understand, what is happening here. first would suggest to use `dumpbin` to see if *tst1* is actually present in export segment of `C` dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name is getting mangled by C++ [decoration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx).  Add `extern "C"` to prevent the mangling of the name:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int tst1(int a);
```